# Calculate position on ground for camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, linear-algebra

I'm trying to calculate the position on the ground that a camera is looking at (without doing a raytrace since I know the forward vector of the camera and the height of the ground). I tried doing this using the dot product but I still seem to be getting the wrong answer. This is what I did with the values I was testing with:

```
const float groundHeight = 0f;
Vector3 cameraPosition = new Vector3(0f, 3f, 0f);
Vector3 cameraForward = new Vector3(0f, -0.7f, 0.7f); //Unit vector

Vector3 positionOnGround = cameraPosition;
positionOnGround.y = groundHeight;
Vector3 cameraToGround = positionOnGround - cameraPosition;

float scalar = Vector3.Dot(cameraToGround, cameraForward);
Vector3 forwardToGround = cameraForward * scalar;
return cameraPosition + forwardToGround;
```

For some reason this is giving me the position 0, 1.5, 1.5 when I'm looking for something that has a height of 0. Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

### Let's define:

- camera is located at point C.
- camera is looking at its target point on the ground (P) (*you want to find P*)
- camera distance from ground `yC = camera.transform.position.y`
- camera projection on the ground (G)
- distance of p from G (zP)
- angle of GCP is a. which in your case it's 45 degrees since CP is (0f, -0.7f, 0.7f)

[image]

### Now

```
tan(a) = magnitude(PG) / magnitude(CG) 
       = zP / yC 
       = zP / camera.transform.position.y

P = new Vector3(xP,yP,zP)
  = new Vector3(xC,0,zP)
  = new Vector3(camera.transform.position.x, 0, tan(a)*camera.transform.position.y)
```